# Error: Activity class MainActivity does not exist

Tags: android, react-native

I'm integrating React Native with an existing android project. When I run the project(`react-native-cli run-android --no-packager`), there is an `error: Activity class MainActivity does not exist.` However, my android project should start with an activity named HomeActivity instead of MainActivity. Sorry for my bad English. The error for a rookie is very difficult. Thank you!

**reproduce step**

1. init a react native project with react-native init yourprojectname
2. run `npm install`
3. go to folder `/yourprojectname/android/app/src/main/java/com/yourprojectname/` 
   rename `MainActivity.java` to `HomeActivity.java`
4. open `HomeActivity.java`, change class name from `MainActivity` to `HomeActivity`
5. go to folder `/yourprojectname/android/app/src/main`
   open `AndroidManifest.xml`, change activity from `MainActivity` to `HomeActivity`
6. run `react-native run-android` an error will jump out `error: Activity class MainActivity does not exist.`

A demo project:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L1mMgb-IV185v52HznFNqLINwvlGIPsf/view?usp=sharing

it's a zip file, please extract it.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -3):

If there's a manifest in whatever IDE you're in, edit that from MainActivity to HomeActivity. Do a clean rebuild after.

Comment: Sorry for reply delay. I already tried clean and rebuild it. But it doesn't work. The android.intent.action.MAIN and android.intent.category.LAUNCHER are marked under homeActivity. React Native just boot from MainActivity which doesn't exits. Anyway,  Thanks for the reply.